# подсвечивать блок только когда он начинает появляться в зоне видимости

Tags: javascript

у меня есть своя наработка, но она отрабатывает с ошибками. Может есть у кого в коллекции?
Вот моя наработка. Тут он когда появляется в зоне видимости 20% от экрана начинает окрашиваться

```
let scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

if ( ( scrollY + document.documentElement.clientHeight * 0.8
        > el.offsetTop &&
        scrollY < el.offsetTop ) ||
        scrollY < el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight &&
        scrollY > el.offsetTop
    ) {
          el.style.backgroundColor = "#999";
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var clientHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
function getCoords(elem) { // кроме IE8-
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset,
    bottom: box.top + pageYOffset + elem.offsetHeight
  };
}
window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if(clientHeight + scrolled > getCoords(test).top && scrolled < getCoords(test).bottom) {
        test.style.background = 'red';
    } else{
        test.style.background = 'black';
    }
};
```

```css
#test{
    background: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2000px;
    transition: 3s;
}
body{
    height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: еще не тестил, но сразу волнует вопрос. Код будет работать и если я буду листать вверх? То есть он окрасится тогда, когда блок появится в верхней части экрана

Comment: @Nikolay, дополнил ответ